# How to add Annotation when use BeanDefinitionRegistry to create bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to create the below-mentioned configuration class programmatically :

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.bns.api.chassis.referenceapp.connector.jpa.repository.db1"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "testdb1UserEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "testdb1UserTransactionManager"
)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ChassisJpaPropertiesList.class)
public class Testdb1Config {...}
```

So as part of the solution, I was thinking to use BeanDefinitionRegistry to register this config class, but I cannot find any way to add the support for @BeanDefinitionRegistry annotation while creating bean though BeanDefinitionBuilder. Is there any way in spring I can add annotation support while creating beans dynamically.